# Programatically determine Mono memory usage in a Xamarin app

Tags: xamarin, memory

To help monitor/track down memory leaks, we need to know what memory our app is consuming.

This is for a Xamarin.Forms app; currently we're only running on Android, but will be on iOS in the future.

I know we can get the OS memory used on the device, in the Droid project, by using code like below:

```
public static MemoryInfo GetMemoryInfo()
{
        MemoryInfo retVal = new MemoryInfo();
        retVal.MaxMemory = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().MaxMemory();
        retVal.FreeMemory = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().FreeMemory();
        retVal.TotalMemory = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().TotalMemory();

        return retVal;
}
```

Is there any mechanism for getting a figure for the memory being consumed in the Mono runtime?

Comment: `System.GC` has plenty of methods for managed memory such as `GetTotalMemory(false)`

Comment: I don't think the way you use is correct. For Xamarin.Android apps, JVM memory usage is just part of the equation. Mono runtime and JVM runs side by side, so you also need to calculate `GC.GetTotalMemory` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys - that's exactly the info I needed. Pretty obvious really! I should have looked at the GC namespace.

Answer (score 0):

As Jon Douglas and Lex Li have pointed out, the answer is to use GC.GetTotalMemory(bool).